# Disabling Quicklook

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have adopted the excellent method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) to associate a file type with my app. My issue is that when the file is attached to an email and the user touches the attachment, instead of the app immediately loading, the user gets a "quicklook" of the contents of the file, and has to click on the button in the top right hand corner in order to "Open With" my app.

I want to DISABLE quicklook in respect of my custom extension (e.g. "*.CUS"), and I want the email app to simply go directly to my app when the attachment is 'clicked'.

Comment: Any new discoveries on this? I'm getting the same, and can't find anything to fix it. Quicklook seems to be not an open thing on iOS, so I can't provide a Quicklook controller to preview my custom file format, and I can't disable this damn "Loading..." thing either.

Comment: No real discoveries, but if you hold your finger down on the file, you can skip the quicklook.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be causing issues with Cisco's Registered Envelope Service (CRES) when using iOS 6. The service encrypts messages in a securedoc.html attachment, which needs to open in Safari and use Javascript in order to function. Now that iOS 6 uses quicklook and gives no other options, this essentially breaks the CRES feature on iOS 6 devices. I'd like to come up with an easy solution to this problem. Does anyone have a solution or workaround to suggest?